# What is batch mode execution in GDB?

Tags: debug, gdb

I read a comment like - "Runs gdb in batch mode".
So wanted to understand what does batch mode execution mean for GDB?
And what is the other mode of execution for GDB?

Answer (score 3):

You can run GDB in various alternative modes, for example, in batch mode or quiet mode. Batch mode refers to batch processing, which means automated processing, without human intervention.

According to GDB documentation :

> Batch mode disables pagination, sets unlimited terminal width and
>   height see Screen Size, and acts as if set confirm off were in effect
>   (see Messages/Warnings).
>
> Batch mode may be useful for running GDB as a filter, for example to
>   download and run a program on another computer; in order to make this
>   more useful, the message "Program exited normally." (which is ordinarily issued whenever a
>   program running under GDB control terminates) is not issued when
>   running in batch mode.

Other mode of execution for GDB are described on [that page](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Mode-Options.html).